# Why is my CSV not saving the data scraped?

Tags: python-3.7

My scraping code is ready. The only problem I have is that I can't save the data in a CSV file. Some help please?

I also tried panda but no luck.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import csv



# open page and grab html
my_url = ('https://www.eia.gov/dnav/ng/hist/rngwhhdD.htm')
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

# HTML parser
page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')

table = []

# Find table
ele_table = page_soup.find("table", summary="Henry Hub Natural Gas 
Spot Price (Dollars per Million Btu)")
# traverse table
col_tag = 'th'
ele_rows = ele_table.find_all('tr', recursive=False)
for ele_row in ele_rows:
    row = []
    ele_cols = ele_row.find_all(col_tag, recursive=False)
    for ele_col in ele_cols:
        # use empty string for no data column
        content = ele_col.string.strip() if ele_col.string else ''
        row.append(content)
    col_tag = 'td'
    # just save row with data
    if any(row):
        table.append(row)

#open CSV file
file = open('GasPrice.csv','wb')
writer = csv.writer(file)


#print table
for row in table:
    print('\t'.join(row))

#Close CSV file
file.close()
```

I expect the Data Scraped to be saved in a CSV file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to write the content into the csv file.

```
 from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
 import csv



# open page and grab html
my_url = ('https://www.eia.gov/dnav/ng/hist/rngwhhdD.htm')
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

# HTML parser
page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')

table = []

# Find table
ele_table = page_soup.find("table", summary="Henry Hub Natural Gas 
Spot Price (Dollars per Million Btu)")
# traverse table
col_tag = 'th'
ele_rows = ele_table.find_all('tr', recursive=False)
for ele_row in ele_rows:
    row = []
    ele_cols = ele_row.find_all(col_tag, recursive=False)
    for ele_col in ele_cols:
        # use empty string for no data column
        content = ele_col.string.strip() if ele_col.string else ''
        row.append(content)
    col_tag = 'td'
    # just save row with data
    if any(row):
        table.append(row)

#open CSV file
file = open('GasPrice.csv','wb')
writer = csv.writer(file)


#print table
for row in table:
    writer.writerow(row)
    print('\t'.join(row))

#Close CSV file
file.close()
```

Comment: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: nvm it worked! Thanks! I also had to change the 'wb' to 'w' for Python 3.